# How do I use external JavaScript libraries with Elm?

Tags: javascript, elm

I've been testing Elm lately for a project but encountered a few problems - one of them is using external JS libraries with Elm (e.g. Moment.js, i18n, firebase etc). I've tried the example below but it doesn't exactly answer what I want:

https://gist.github.com/evancz/e69723b23958e69b63d5b5502b0edf90

According to the example, I have to create individual programs just to port the module out and generate a static .js files for each of them. Is it possible to just write all the ports in one single file and what are the best practices for using port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> According to the example, I have to create individual programs just to port the module out and generate a static .js files for each of them.

I don't believe this is true.  The spelling example you link to is only intended to be an example of how to use ports.  You don't have to compile each part of your program that uses a port into its own separate .js file.

You could put all the ports in one module, but I would hesitate to do this.  In my opinion a better approach would be to have one port module for each external JS library you want to use, and put all the ports you use for communicating with that library in that module.  That way, the responsibility of each such module is clear.  Then, compile you whole Elm application, port modules and all, into one .js file.

> what are the best practices for using port?

Well, this is a bit open-ended.  Nonetheless, from my somewhat limited experience:

- Keep port-handling in separate modules, and don't declare a module as a `port module` if it doesn't need to be.
- Ensure you test the integration with the third-party libraries thoroughly, in particular with error cases.  Elm will throw an exception if the type of data coming through a port from an external library back into Elm isn't as you've declared it to be.
- If you can find an Elm package that does the same as an external JS library, consider using that instead.